# Failure to loadfile using JLink to nRF51822

Tags: cortex-m

I have built a PCB that uses the nRF51822 (Nordic's cortex-m0 + BLE SOIC).  I am failing to load the binary onto the chip.  I can:

1. connect to the nRF51822 on my mac using the JLinkExe.
2. execute the erase command in JLink

I have a small binary called LED_TEST.hex that I attempt to load.  No matter how many times I run loadfile, I get the message:

Downloading file [LED_TEST.hex]...Info: J-Link: Flash download: Restarting flash programming due to program error (possibly skipped erasure of half-way erased sector).
Info: J-Link: Flash download: Skip optimizations disabled for second try.
Error while programming flash: Programming failed.

I'm looking for ideas on how to best debug this.  I have files that I logged the SWD traffic into.  I am new to SWD traffic, and there are A LOT of records...so i'm not sure where would be the best place to focus within the SWD traffic in order to tip me off why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I use MBED platform and REDBearLab's dongle, which is almost a free alternative solution.
You can refer this one: http://www.instructables.com/id/16mm-Bluetooth-69-DOF-Gyroscope-Wearable-Board-tal/

hope helpful